# Ios Launch Image wont delete

Tags: ios

Hi I have created an App but changed the Default.png image halfway through now it only loads the old one but in the summary page in xcode it shows the new image as being the default but in the simulator it loads the old image and on my iphone it doesnt load anything. it also wont let me delete it and re add it it still uses the old image or no image.

I have tried

cleaning the project
deleting it off the phone and simulator

its still the same

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have deleted any other images titled "default.png" in the Project Navigator. To do so just right-click on the image and hit delete. If it isn't allowing you to delete it, rename it to something else besides "default.png". Hope you can solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried renaming the image to be something other that Default.png? You can see details on how to do that here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the plist in xcode under icons? With me it happened to have 6 icons listed.

[image]

It also helps to do a reset contents and settings on the simulator.